# boost: read_until "\n" reads until " "

Tags: c++, boost-asio, iostream

I'm developing a tcp client using boost::asio to process incoming text, that ends with "\n". However, when I am sending text containing whitespace, it drops all characters after the first whitespace appears. I've already verified that the text I'm sending is complete.

This is my code:

```
boost::system::error_code error; 
boost::asio::streambuf buffer; 
boost::asio::read_until( *socket, buffer, "\n", error ); 
std::istream str(&buffer); 
std::string s; 
str >> s;
```

Comment: It's `>>` that grabs the first word in the buffer, not boost dropping the text

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `std::getline` instead of `>>`, which is what stops reading on encountering whitespace:

```
std::istream str(&buffer); 
std::string s; 
std::getline(str, s);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 std::istream str(&buffer); 
 std::string s; 
 str >> s;
```

If this is how you are checking the contents of the buffer, then you got it wrong. This would read a `std::string` from the string, which reads up to the first whitespace character. That's what the `std::string operator<<` does. If you keep doing `>> s` you'll get the rest of your information. Instead you could use `std::getline` to retrieve the entire content.